# Databinding controls, best practices for encapsulation

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I've recently been using data binding in c#, and while the way I am doing it is straightforward and works, it does not feel like the best way.

For example, I have a manager class, ie UserManager which has the following interface:

```
class UserManager
{
  public IList<User> Users { get; ...}
  public AddUser(...)
  public RemoveUser(...)
}
```

So `Adduser` and `RemoveUser` should control the list, with the `Users` collection as an output.  I am using this collection in a binding, ie:

```
listBindingSource.DataSource = userManager.Users;
```

I am then manipulating the list via the binding, ie

```
listBindingSource.Add(new User(...))
```

This works, of course, but I am completely bypassing the `UserManager` and the `AddUser`/`RemoveUser` functions in there!  This of course seems very wrong.  What is the correct way to use databinding?

`UserManager` is inside a lib so I do not want to put any binding objects in there, as I feel that should be a gui thing.  On the other hand, with binding, my gui has taken complete control over my collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code stands now, you can't do what you're after. At some point, the collection has to support the `IBindingList` interface (which is what the `BindingSource` object you have on the form does). If you want to make use of your `UserManager` class to do the manipulations, for practical purposes you'll have to change the internal data store for the `Users` property to use a `BindingList<User>` (you should still be able to return it typed as an `IList<User>` as you have now, just change the actual concrete implementation to `BindingList<User>`). Doing this will expose the `IBindingList` interface to the grid and it will detect changes that are made elsewhere, namely in your `UserManager` class.

This will, however, only cause it to pick up on changes made to the *list*, not to individual elements contained in the list (in other words, additions and removals will be reflected on the UI, but modifications won't be). In order to accomplish this, you need to implement `IPropertyChanged` on the `User` class (assuming it doesn't already).

Comment: Thank you, this is very good information.  I'm a little concerned with having to specify my internal list as a BindingList, as I feel it should not need to know how it is going to be used.  But I suppose the alternative would be some intermediate converting layer, which is not really worth it for a small project.

Comment: `BindingList` is designed to be presentation-agnostic. All it does is provide the necessary infrastructure for detecting changes. No matter WHAT data binding scenario you use, there *has* to be a change-tracking (or, more precisely, *change notification*) system in place in order for changes to the data to be reflected automatically on the GUI. There is nothing "smelly" about using `BindingList<T>`.